# Continent, country, city Has-A relationship

Tags: java, inheritance, model-view-controller, composition

How would I structurally represent a Continent object's relationship with its Country object.  And each Country object could potentially have several City objects.  I am currently using an MVC Model, in which GeoModel contains an ArrayList then each Continent in the List contains an ArrayList then each Country in that list contains an ArrayList.  Does this sound like a proper way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds good. give it a try, then come back with issues you get

Comment: You probably want to use Set instead of List.

Comment: What if I will be sorting and searching the database?

Comment: Actually I am required to use a List now that I look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, a `Continent` object is composed of `Country` objects, which are composed of `City` objects. This can be directly expressed in a UML class diagram.

In Java code, you get

```
class Continent {
  ...
  LinkedList<Country> countries;
  ...
}
class Country{
  ...
  LinkedList<City> cites;
  ...
}
```

Of course, you can also use `ArrayList`instead of `LinkedList`.